# Vimeo API filter results

Tags: api, filter, vimeo, endpoint

Have to admit that I'm new to using the Vimeo API, but I've searched for an answer here and I can't find documentation on what I'm looking for.

I'm using the Api and familiarizing myself with the endpoints. There are two endpoints that I need to merge in my call. I can make the separate calls successfully, but I haven't found a way to get what I need.

I'm working with the tags endpoint:
https://api.vimeo.com/tags/{tag}/videos

I'm also working with the users endpoint:
https://api.vimeo.com/users/{user_id}/videos

basically what I need to do is somehow (using parameters?) filter the videos returned by the user endpoint by tag, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The query parameter on user videos (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/users#/{user_id}/videos) allows you to search based on title, description and tags.

Currently there is no way to filter video queries based on a list of tags, but it's planned for the future!

Comment: Seeing how it's been a few years, has this been implemented yet ? Nothing in the documentation seems to reflect it.